# How to make form state invalid when using setError in react-hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, react-forms

I am using react-hook form and my field type is a custom component which returns me an error. Now I cannot write the rules in validate function as I am getting the error in a callback from my component. I have used `setError` method to explicitly set the error. However my form state is still valid and I cannot prevent form submission. I want to disable submit button if an error is returned from my component.

I have read in the react-hook form docs that the `isValid` property of the form is only derived by the validation result from your input registration rules or schema result. I want to set the `isValid` property to false when I receive an error in my callback. Any ideas on this. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
 const setLogoError = () => {
  defaultValues.setError('logo', { type: 'custom', message: 'custom message' });
 }
```

Comment: not enough information to observe the issue, please provide more code, may be your form and how you tried to disabled the button, etc